# mysql : sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables & hangs

Tags: mysql

I have accidentally deleted all mysql users and hence not able to access any database.

i am using http://www.kevssite.com/2011/07/02/deleted-rootlocalhost-account-in-mysql/ link to recreate root user account again.

but the problem is that whenever I issue command  `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &` my scripts hangs forever. because of this i am not able to follow next steps mentioned in the above given link.

```
 mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.
151130 18:17:51 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
151130 18:17:51 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to kill `mysqld` first before running `mysqld_safe`:

```
killall mysqld mysqld_safe
# give it 10 seconds or so to shut down cleanly
ps aux | grep mysqld
# if you still see mysqld, more violent action might be needed,
# but it might
# corrupt your data. But if it a test or empty install, no problem
killall -9 mysqld mysqld_safe
# now mysqld_safe should start
```

And you should also remove either `syslog` or `log-error` from `my.cnf` to address the complaint in the first error message from `mysqld_safe`.